# Changing thumb color of a scroll pane in runtime

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx

I´m trying to change the color of the scroll pane´s thumb in runtime.
For changing the background color of the scroll pane in runtime I use this code:

```
sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+colorToHex());//sp is the scroll pane
//colorToHex return the color in hexadecimal.
```

I´m not able to change the thumb color in runtime.

For change the thumb color in css I use this:

```
.scrollpane :vertical .thumb{
    -fx-background-color:black;
    -fx-background-radius: 18 18 18 18; 
}
```

How can I access to thumb style in runtime and change it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the inline style of the thumb node, you need direct access to that node. However, I think this is not possible without creating your own `ScrollPaneSkin` and `ScrollBarSkin`.

Why not changing the style by linking the scrollpane with a CSS stylesheet file at runtime:

```
 sp.getStylesheets().addAll("<package>/my-scrollbar.css");
```

my-scrollbar.css:

```
.scroll-bar:vertical > .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```